# How to get rowspan into td element of table in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS 1.3, I'm creating a table from an array I've defined in my controller.  Basically, I have the array:

```
sessionOverviewTrs = [{rowspan: 1},{rowspan: 2},..]
```

I've got code like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="trs in list.sessionOverviewTrs">
   <td ng-repeat="tds in trs track by $index">
        {{ tds.rowspan}}
```

The problem is I really want to put the rowspan on the td ng-repeat="tds... but I can't figure out to do that.  I feel like I want to put my repeater for the td one level up in a div or something, then have the td executed with the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to simply add the `rowspan` attribute?

```
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="trs in sessionOverviewTrs">
   <td ng-repeat="tds in trs track by $index" colspan="{{tds.colspan}}" rowspan="{{tds.rowspan}}">
        {{tds.value}}
    </td></tr></table>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/gtk7anup/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="trs in list.sessionOverviewTrs">
    <td ng-repeat="tds in trs track by $index" rowspan="{{tds.rowspan}}">
```